# Microsoft Navision PMT Formula

Tags: excel, navision

I'm trying to compare Microsoft Navision and Excel PMT formulas but they both give different values for monthly payment. Is there anyone who know the reason of why it happens? Here is example down below.

1. Annual Rate: 38.8%
2. Number of payments: 36
3. Loan Amount: 2625

Microsoft Excel PMT Result is: 124.46

Micrisoft Navision PMT Result is: 124.67

Comment: There is no pmt function in Nav so it depends on how it was implemented. Do you have code of the function?

Comment: @MakSim No i dont have navision side code :( If I had it I would figure out with that issue